# Are magnetic vortices capable of providing magnetic lensing when observed away from the poles

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, milky-way, image-processing, origin-of-life

Magnetic vortices-(ESA cluster mission from observations November 2018)(article, ESA, science & exploration: 'Magnetic Vortices explain mysterious auroral beads'. An observer during Saturn's recent opposition looks to the sky and notices auroral beads in what appears as a line of progression across the night sky. The progression appears as black spheres and white spheres or beads. Could the vortices be looked through as a lens?

https://www.ucl.ac.uk/mssl/research/solar-system/planetary-science/planetary-science-research

https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Images/2022/06/Magnetic_vortices_explain_mysterious_auroral_beads

[www.space.com/17661-theory-general-relavity.html](http://www.space.com/17661-theory-general-rela%EE%80%9Fvity.html)

Comment: This sounds interesting but please add a link to a discussion of “ Magnetic vortices-(cassini cluster mission)” so that I and many other readers will have a clue what it is. Thanks! And *welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: There is an ESA Cluster II mission to study Earth's magnetosphere, which has nothing to do with the Cassini mission. Magnetic vortices and their relation to auroral beads are one of the things it studies. I've got no idea what the black spheres/white spheres stuff is about or what the question is actually asking.

Comment: All links are broken for me. But no, magnetic lenses or beads don't lens light; the name refers to their shape in the tail of magnetospheres. Likely the black and white is illustration to indicate polarity

Comment: Looks like you've pasted the links as text with ligatures.

Comment: Ok, I learn that "A magnetic lens is a device for the focusing or deflection of moving charged particles, such as electrons or ions, by use of the magnetic Lorentz force." and it doesn't refer to light being lensed, but particle beams or streams https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_lens